# java serialization

Tags: java, serialization, tibco-rv

I am trying to write message to a file using serialization.Message consists of two fields-
date and `TibrvMsg`(`TibrvMsg` is a propriotory message by Tibco and this class is not serializable as per their documentation).So my custom message is:

```
Message msg = new Message(TibrvMsg msg)
```

Problem is though i am declaring `Message Serializable`, i am not able to serialize it as `TibrvMsg` is not serializable.
So i get `java.io.NotSerializableException: com.tibco.tibrv.TibrvMsg` exception.

Comment: can you please post your code so that it can be more clear

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use a [serialization proxy](http://www.newt.com/java/effective-java-reloaded.pdf). Serialization proxy is a different class altogether than the object being serialized with the logical state of the object. The Object readResolve() method to write a proxy instead of this object and create an object by reading proxy.

Some semi-pseudo code:

```
class Message implements Serializable {

  private Date dt;
  private TibrvMsg msg;

  private Object writeReplace() {
     return new Proxy(this);
  }

  private static class Proxy implements Serializable {
     private Date dt;
     private Map msgData;

     Proxy(Message msg) {
        this.dt = msg.dt;
        this.msgData = doTransform(msg.msg, "UTF-16");
     }

     private Object readResolve() {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.dtd = dt;
        msg.msg = asTibrvMsg(msgData);
        return msg;
     }
  }
}
```

Additionally override readObject(ObjectInputStream) to throw an InvalidObjectException. The serialization proxy pattern also has certain security [advantages](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=serialization+proxy+pattern&source=bl&ots=yXKhNju2Q4&sig=kIGgdsI9sAmY3R3jPu-OdDQSaRw&hl=en&ei=bUZyTMSsAZPKcfvpwLIN&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=serialization%20proxy%20pattern&f=false) over normal serialization. It also has a few [disadvantages](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=serialization+proxy+pattern&source=bl&ots=yXKhNju2Q4&sig=kIGgdsI9sAmY3R3jPu-OdDQSaRw&hl=en&ei=bUZyTMSsAZPKcfvpwLIN&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=serialization%20proxy%20pattern&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a way to represent your TibrvMsg as a serializable object (maybe something [like this](http://svn.muleforge.org/tibcorv/src/main/java/org/mule/providers/rvd/TibrvMsgToMap.java), which transforms it into a Map).

You can then override the following two methods to write this data to the output stream (or read it):

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
     throws IOException{
    out.writeObject(date);
    out.writeObject(doSomethingWithTibrv(tibrv);
}

 private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
     date = (Date) in.readObject();
     tibrv = readTibrv(in.readObject());
 }
```

Comment: Thanks.I am doing exactly the same.But program throws an exception.One option i see is to get various fields from TibrvMsg and attach to Message and then write Message to file.

Comment: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.tibco.tibrv.TibrvMsg
TibrvMsg contains key value pairs.I will get them and then include as a part of Message before writing it to file.

Comment: you should not be getting this exception if your writeObject works properly.

Comment: You should always add `defaultReadObject`/`getFields` (read?) and `defaultWriteObject`/`putFields` (write?) to the start of `readObject`  and `writeObject`. (And add necessary `transient` or `serialPeristentFields` (spelt correctly).)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "this class is not serializable as per their documentation"?
Couldent you just extend their class and implement serializable? Its just a marker interface, so...

Comment: yes.I can do that.But I was wondering why they didn't privide that.Anyway, i have found that one method getAsBytes() in TibRvMsg class that  returns byte array of message and documentation says that this can be used to archive the message.

Comment: If you extend a class and implement `Serializable`, the fields of the base class are not serialisable (for good reason) and the no-arg constructor is used for initialisation instead.